# CoffeeScript `?` Operator

Tags: coffeescript

What inputs can I use to make this function throw the `Value required...` error?

```
requiresValue = (fn) ->
  ->
    throw "Value required" unless arg? for arg in arguments
    fn.apply(this, arguments)

foo = (x) ->
  x

console.log requiresValue(foo)(undefined) # returns undefined
console.log requiresValue(foo)(null)      # returns null
```

I'm confused as to why passing in `undefined` or `null` wouldn't cause that exception to be thrown given my testing in the REPL:

```
coffee> null?
false
coffee> undefined?
false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arg? for arg in arguments
```

returns a list of booleans. Which, being not empty, is evaluated as truthy.

Your test can to be (edit: `arguments` is apparently not a real array, therefore we need a real array first):

```
args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
throw "Value required" unless args.length and args.every (arg) -> arg?
```

(edit: added test for arguments emptiness)

Comment: in the original `arg? for arg in arguments`, why would the following return inputs **not** throw an error? `requiresValue(foo)([])` (returns []) or `requiresValue(foo)()` (returns undefined) or ``requiresValue(foo)` (returns Function`?. **P.S** If I understand correctly, the intent of the check is to throw an error if **no arguments** are present, right?

Comment: `[]` is considered truthy.

Comment: however, please note that `args.every (arg) -> arg?` too is considered true if there is no item in the args. I just added `args.length and ` to assert the case where args is empty.

Comment: also, in `requiresValue(foo)([])`, `arguments` is `[[]]` (it contains an element which is an empty array), which makes it a valid input, even if you consider that there should be at least one element (unless you want to consider `[]` is not a valid input, in which case the function in `every` needs to be slightly more complex)

Comment: @KevinMeredith: `if no arguments are present` not quite. The original function tests if the arguments are valid. No argument would be considered valid in this case. The function I edited rejects empty arguments. To only test if there are no arguments, `throw "Value required" unless arguments.length` is sufficient

Comment: `[] is truthy`. I don't understand wrt to this example: `coffee> [] is true` evaluates to `false`

Comment: `not true` returns `false`. `not []` also returns `false`.

Comment: @KevinMeredith: because `[] is true` compiles to `[] === true;`, which is absolute equality (therefore false). Like @hpaulj suggested, forcing cast to boolean can be done using `not` (or `not not` if you need to truth value)

Answer (score 0):

This version of your test might make things clearer:

```
requiresValue = (fn) ->
  ->
    for arg in arguments
      if not arg?
        throw 'value error'
    fn.apply(this, arguments)
```

It should be functionally similar to njzk2's answer, except for the case of no arguments (I dont' have a `args.length` test.

Also note in the compiled code that the `arg?` is rendered as:

```
if (arg == null) {
    throw 'value error';
  }
```

In Javascript `== null` has a clearly spelled out functionality.

Comment: I usually see `if not arg?` compiled as `if (typeof arg === "undefined" || arg === null)` (I have never seen so far anything in coffee that compiles as `==`, only as `===`)

Comment: Put that `if not arg?` in a loop and see the simpler version.

Comment: wow. this is totally weird. I wonder why this is treated differently.

Comment: `x==null` is a safe test if we know that `x` has been assigned, such as in `a.x==null` or the loop.  But if I do `x==null` in the `node` shell I get a `ReferenceError`.  The longer test gets around that.

Comment: so it has to be tested for undefined first, but in the loop it cannot be undefined, since it just has been defined. makes sense.

Comment: `var w; w==null` returns `true`.  That's because `w` was referenced first; it's just that its value is `undefined`.  More on `undefined` at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined